# While/foreach does not fetching the value from database

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to fetch some values from database but while/foreach does not work.

```
<?php
$type_id = $article->type_id;
$sql = " SELECT * FROM `interior_image_testing` WHERE `type_id` = '$type_id' ";
//echo $sql;
//$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {


    //echo $result;
    $obj = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


    foreach ($obj as $objs):
        ?>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6 workimg">
            <img src="assets/img/<?php echo $objs['image_path']; ?> " width="100%"> <!-- needs to be changed -->
        </div> 


        <?php
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

The problem is, I can not get the value from database.
In the `interior_testing` table I've got `type_id`, `name`, `location`, and `profile_pic`
In the `interior_image_testing` table I've got `id`, `image_path`, and `type_id`.

On the page, the image is not getting fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `foreach` there. You need to repeatedly call `mysqli_fetch_array` in order to retrieve all results. One call will just retrieve one result row at once:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['image_path'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {...}
```

You need to loop with $result, instead of array given after the first query. Here you can see the correct usage;

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php